# SQL/PHP Query Insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table which has 3 columns, (Latitude, Longitude, and Username).

How can I query the location and insert the values into a specific username. What I have so far is

```
"INSERT INTO Users (Latitude, Longitude) VALUES WHERE Username = '" . $username . "' ("' . $latitude . "', '" . $longitude . "')";
```

I'm fairly confident that that won't work from the debugging i've done. Thank you guys so much for the future help!

Comment: You don't `insert` with conditions, that's what [`update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) is for

Comment: This looks terrifyingly insecure. Are you **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use INSERT to **UPDATE** a record. Assuming `$latitude` and `$longitude` are not user supplied and/or are escaped properly:

```
$sql="UPDATE `users`
SET `Latitude` = '$latitude',
`Longitude` = '$longitude'
WHERE `Username` = '$username'";
```

Comment: They are user supplied, from an IOS device

Comment: Then **definitely** make sure those values are escaped, or better yet, use prepared statements to prevent SQL injections.